# R: function or similar to sum up number of non-NA values for columns that contain specific characters in large data set

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr

I have a large data set (907 x 1855). I need to count how many follow-ups each patient have had. A follow-up column contain either `1`, `2` or `NA` and a follow-up may be defined as the specific column being `!is.na()`.

There are up to max 20 follow-ups. As you can see, each follow up has the `_vX` added as suffix where `x` correspond to the number of follow-up.

Thus, `follow-up` nr `20` has the very inconvenient `RedCap`autogenerated column name `p$fu_location_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19_v20`

```
> head(p)
  fu_location fu_location_v2 fu_location_v2_v3 fu_location_v2_v3_v4    ...
1           1              1                 1                    1    ...
2           2              2                 1                    2    ...
3           1              1                 1                    2    ...
4           2              2                 2                    2    ...
```

I need to count the number of `!is.na(for column names that contains "fu_location")`. I tried `mutate(n_fu = sum(!is.na(contains("fu_location"))))` but that did not work.

Preferably, the solution is in `dplyr`. Perhaps a function?

Expected output:

```
> head(p)
  fu_location fu_location_v2 fu_location_v2_v3 fu_location_v2_v3_v4    n_fu
1           1              1                 1                    1       8
2           2              2                 1                    2      20
3           1              1                 1                    2       4
4           2              2                 2                    2       4
```

Data

```
p <- structure(list(fu_location = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), fu_location_v2 = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), fu_location_v2_v3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), fu_location_v2_v3_v4 = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), fu_location_v2_v3_v4_v5 = c(2L, 2L, NA, NA), fu_location_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6 = c(1L, 
2L, NA, NA), fu_location_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7 = c(2L, 1L, NA, NA
), fu_location_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8 = c(1L, 2L, NA, NA), fu_location_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9 = c(NA, 
2L, NA, NA), fu_location_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10 = c(NA, 
1L, NA, NA), fu_location_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11 = c(NA, 
2L, NA, NA), fu_location_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12 = c(NA, 
1L, NA, NA), fu_location_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13 = c(NA, 
2L, NA, NA), fu_location_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14 = c(NA, 
2L, NA, NA), fu_location_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15 = c(NA, 
1L, NA, NA), fu_location_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16 = c(NA, 
2L, NA, NA), fu_location_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17 = c(NA, 
1L, NA, NA), fu_location_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18 = c(NA, 
2L, NA, NA), fu_location_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19 = c(NA, 
1L, NA, NA), fu_location_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19_v20 = c(NA, 
2L, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rowSums` :

```
library(dplyr)
p %>% mutate(n_fu =  rowSums(!is.na(select(., contains('fu_location')))))
```

Or in base :

```
p$n_fu <- rowSums(!is.na(p[grep('fu_location', names(p))]))
```